# How to upload an image into RStudio Notebook?

Tags: r, image, rstudio, r-markdown

Does anyone know how to import/upload a png image from a (working) directory into a RStudio Notebook script? I like to include it in the HTML output from the Notebook. 
The suggested script in Rmarkdown (http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_basics.html) does not work in Notebook.

Here is some code that I have used/created:

```
#' Plot pathways using the bioconductor *pathview* package. Five *.png images are placed in the working directory by default.
>p <- pathview(gene.data=foldchanges, pathway.id=keggresids, species="hsa"))
>str(p)
```

The log of 'str(p)' is a list of 5 (one for each pathway) each consisting of a data.frame plot.data.gene with 10 variables and a plot.data.cpd: NULL

One can use the example on p.3-6 of the pathview vignette (https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/bioc/vignettes/pathview/inst/doc/pathview.pdf).

Since the image is printed to the working directory, it won't show up in my Notebook HTML. Is there a way to import the image back into the document so it will render into the HTML document? I am not working in a markdown document, but in a regular R script that I compile into an HTML Notebook by selecting the Notebook icon on (or ctrl+shift+K), hence the following markdown script won't work:

```
![imagename](/images/file.png)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have only tried what Rmarkdown suggested, and have no other ideas

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, as it is not clear what you are asking. As a general rule-of-thumb with very few exceptions, every SO question should include code, and data as well if it is needed to execute. The two downvotes are almost certainly triggered by the lack of code.

Comment: code has been added. Thank you Mike.

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, is this what you want? Just inserting a png into a R markdown file?

````
---
title: "Crab"
output: html_document
---

#![Here is a Crab](Crab.png)

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Hi @MikeWise thank you for your very good answer. I tried to do it and a # symbol appears to the left of the figure. Why?

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty old question, but I have a working solution and found this question while looking for my solution.

To add an image from a website (taken directly from a Markdown cheatsheet by Adam Pritchard):

```
![alt text](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png "Logo Title Text 1")
```

Or to add an image from your local drive, use the following (works on Mac OSX):

```
![Fancy image description](/Users/path/to/you/file.png)
```